# Making disabled field in ModelForm subclass

Tags: python, django, forms

I got a model `Layout` in my Django app with the following fields:

- `meta_layout` - `ForeignKey` on model `MetaLayout`
- `name` - `CharField`
- `edited` - `DateTimeField`
- `is_active` - `BooleanField`

And I have two views using this model - one called `NewLayout` and other `EditLayout` each subclassing standard `CreateView` and `UpdateView` accordingly. In `EditLayout` view I want to use some special form that looks the same as form used in `NewLayout` (which is simply plain `ModelForm` for this model) but has `meta_layout` select field displayed with **attribute disabled="disabled"** (e.d. user can choose meta_layout for each Layout only once - while creating it). Ok, I can create custom `ModelForm` where widget for `meta_layout` field has the desired attribute, but the problem is actually that when such attribute set on form field it **will not send any values with request** - so my validation fails trying to check value for this field and select element does not support "readonly" attribute which will would be just fine here.

I found some really ugly hack to workaround this:

```
#Here is my Form:
class LayoutEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    meta_layout = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=MetaLayout.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs=dict(disabled='disabled')),
        empty_label=None,
        required=False) # if required=True validation will fail
                        # because value is not supplied in POST

    class Meta:
        fields = ('meta_layout', 'name', 'is_active')
        model = Layout

class EditLayout(UpdateView):

    ...

    # And one modified method from my View-class
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(EditLayout, self).get_form_kwargs()
        # actually POST parameters
        if kwargs.has_key('data'):
            # can't change QueryDict itself - it's immutable
            data = dict(self.request.POST.items())
            # emulate POST params from ModelChoiceField
            data['meta_layout'] = u'%d' % self.object.meta_layout.id
            kwargs['data'] = data
        return kwargs
```

But I believe that it's non-Django, non-Pythonic and not a good-programming-style-at-all of doing such simple thing. Can you suggest any better solution?

Edit:
Oh, I found much less ugly solution: added this in my form class:

```
def clean_meta_layout(self):
    return self.instance.meta_layout
```

But I still open for suggestions) - may I missed something?

Comment: your update is indeed a good solution because having a disabled field doesn't prevent a user from posting that data manually.